# Joining multiple columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a dataframe where I need to combine multiple columns into one. The names of dogs are in different columns(doggo, floofer, pupper and puppo), I want to be able to combine them under a new column name 'dog_type' and also select the ones with values. Where it is 'doggo' under the column 'doggo' should return the same under the new column 'dog_type'. Thank you in advance.

[Update] Taking a cue from @Elda's answer below, this is what I intend to achieve. I need help to select only where the value of column'doggo' has a value of 'doggo' for instance. Thank you all for all the help.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'doggo': ['None', 'None', 'None', 'doggo'],
                   'floofer': ['None', 'floofer', 'None', 'None'],
                    'pupper':['None', 'None', 'None', 'pupper'],
                    'puppo':['None', 'None', 'None', 'None']})

df['dog_type'] = df[df.columns[0:]].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna().astype(str)),
    axis=1)
df
```

Comment: Hi. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
 import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    
    df = pd.DataFrame({'doggo': ['None', 'None', 'None', 'doggo'],
                       'floofer': ['None', 'floofer', 'None', 'None'],
                        'pupper':['None', 'None', 'None', 'pupper'],
                        'puppo':['None', 'None', 'None', 'None']})
    
    df[0:4].replace('None', np.nan, inplace=True)
    
    df['dog_type'] = df[df.columns[0:]].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna().astype(str)),
    axis=1)
    
    df
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. Permission to reproducing your code with some modifications to show what I wanted to achieve: import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'doggo': ['None', 'None', 'None', 'doggo'],
                   'floofer': ['None', 'floofer', 'None', 'None'],
                    'pupper':['None', 'None', 'None', 'pupper'],
                    'puppo':['None', 'None', 'None', 'None']})

df['dog_type'] = df[df.columns[0:]].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna().astype(str)),
    axis=1)
df